# Is there a way to deal with nested generics using Class<T>

Tags: java, generics

If you look at the this vey simple code snipped, is there a valid way to actually call `baz`?

```
public class Foo {
    static class Bar<T> {
        public void baz(Class<? extends List<T>> cls) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar<String> bar = new Bar<>();

        // does not compile
        bar.baz(ArrayList<String>.class);
        bar.baz((Class<List<String>>) ArrayList.class);
        bar.baz(new ArrayList<String>().getClass());
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Can you explain us why do you want to do such a thing ? Because at the moment a perfectly valid answer to your question would be `bar.baz(null)` but I strongly doubt it could help you... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways (they both have their disadvantages):

1.

```
Bar bar = new Bar<>();
bar.baz(ArrayList.class);
```

This of course removes the `String` type parameter, which you might not want.

2.

```
Bar<String> bar = new Bar<>();
bar.baz(MyClass.class);
```

Here, `MyClass` is declared like a wrapper of `ArrayList<String>`:

```
class MyClass implements List<String> {
    private ArrayList<String> inner = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return inner.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return inner.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return inner.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return inner.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return inner.toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        return inner.toArray(a);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(String s) {
        return inner.add(s);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return inner.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return inner.containsAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends String> c) {
        return inner.addAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends String> c) {
        return inner.addAll(index, c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return inner.removeAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return inner.retainAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        inner.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public String get(int index) {
        return inner.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public String set(int index, String element) {
        return inner.set(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, String element) {
        inner.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    public String remove(int index) {
        return inner.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        return inner.indexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        return inner.lastIndexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<String> listIterator() {
        return inner.listIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<String> listIterator(int index) {
        return inner.listIterator(index);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return inner.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }
}
```

The disadvantage of this is of course, wasting time to create a brand new class that implements `List<String>`. If you are lazy, you can try extending `AbstractList<String>` instead.

Comment: actually in my specific case variant 2 is in fact an option, thx for pointing this out!